# Sending messages through application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In a Facebook application, is there anyway I can let a user send a message to another user (to his Inbox)? Even if there is no direct access, is there some kind of a link structure I can use such as:
"facebook.com/example?sendTO=**user-id**" that will prompt a facebook popup to send a message a user?

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a message to another user via facebook's apis as no function exist for this. The only way to send personal and private messages are via emails (proxified or not), then the user must install your application and accept to share its email.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "messages" in between the link:

If the persons id is `https://www.facebook.com/some.one.007` then write

```
https://www.facebook.com/messages/some.one.007
```

Thats it.